# Intuition behind $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, cv.complex-variables

In literature, there are many proofs of the well-known result $$\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

However, as far as I know, they do not offer an *intuitive* explanation of why this result *should* be true.

So my question is:

> What is the key intuition -- that is, the picture --  behind the result? Are there any *visual* of anyway *intuitive* proofs of the statement?

Comment: Euler's first proof is very intuitive to me: find a "polynomial" whose roots are the non-zero integers (so your "polynomial" is sin/x) then use the relation between the sum of the inverse of the square of the roots and the first coefficients. Voilà.

Comment: @Olivier I see what you mean, but honestly, from my limited experience, that is not what I call intuitive.

Comment: Not everything in maths can be justified by a reason that feels "intuitive", and "intuition" is highly subjective

Comment: @Dal, you don't need intuition, you need Euler.

Comment: John von Neumann said something like this: *young man, you don't understand (things) in mathematics, you get used to (them)*.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński: I think this was his reply to an engineer who didn't understand the method of characteristics. Alas, it makes no sense to me either :(

Comment: Could there be a motivic reason? Isn't Grothendieck's conjecture supposed to imply that all algebraic relations between periods have a geometric origin? Zeta(2) appears as a period of pi_1(P^1-{0,1,infty})- it would come up in H^3 of a quotient of (P^1-{0,1,infty})^3.

Comment: @Alex, just after (not before :-) I posted the above quote from JvN, I searched for it. <a href="https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann">Wikiquote</a> provides the following version: **Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them.** And indeed, Alex, the quote is followed by this note: *Reply to Dr. Felix T. Smith at Stanford Research Institute who had said "I'm afraid I don't understand the method of characteristics."*.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689315) might prove to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word intuitive by definition means that something "feels correct", and is very myopic. The fact that there are so many different proofs is in itself a gift because you can pick your favorite and intuit all you want.

I like Euler's proof because it shows how it's related to the taylor series of $\sin(x)$ and so the mystery of $\pi$ and 6 becomes less mysterious.

On the other hand someone with lots of experience in Fourier analysis will see it as the Fourier transform of something and again the appearance of $\pi$, particular $\pi^2$ becomes apparent from Parseval's identity.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short note by Robert E. Greene (UCLA):

[How Geometry implies $\sum \frac{1}{k^2} = \pi^2/6$](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~greene/How%20Geometry.pdf)

Comment: I feel that this proof only uses geometry in name, kind of like the "topological" proof of Euclids theorem of infinitely many primes. It's a neat proof nevertheless.